# Asp.Net Web API Block Arbitrary text on 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, penetration-testing

In my application (Asp.Net web api) if the attacker inserts arbitrary text after in the api url then that text is displayed in the 404 error page. This can be used by attacker to trick the users to click on custom links or for phishing attacks.[image]
[image]

I want to block any arbitrary text from showing up on error page like this. Point to note here, we have not implemented GUID based error messaging in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set up a custom 404 error page add the following to web.config inside <system.web></system.web>:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

I’ve set mode="On" so we can view the custom errors pages locally. Generally you would only want to display these in production so would set mode="RemoteOnly"

Then add also custom error pages in IIS (note that this only works in IIS 7+). In web.config add the following inside <system.webServer></system.webServer>:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

If it doesn't help, as I don't know the architecture of your application, you should go for a route matching solution:

- Implementing a smart IHttpRouteConstraint
- Applying the constraint to attribute routing
- Applying the constraint to centralized routing

here are the details of the implementation:
https://www.strathweb.com/2014/10/route-matching-overriding-404-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thank you for your response.
What I need is something which can handle the custom message being displayed on the error page in my web api:

http://localhost:12345/web-api/api/MY CUSTOM MESSAGE

Now here the attacker can add custom message to any part of the above url (except domain ofcourse), this message would get reflected in the 404 error page along with the requested url. 
I want to stop that message being reflected in the custom url for the entire application, regardless of what user enters and on which part of url he attacks.

Hope I was able to clarify.

Comment: @SushantRawat I think the only way is to add a custom 404 page in the web.config, enabling customErrors and redirecting to an HTML page, and you must enable the WebApi to serve static files

Comment: Could you please guide me to an article for help on the same?